# mystery dot unknown problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

hello I've been modelling a face only got from the eye brows to the mouth. around the left eye there's a dot that is visible only in object mode not in edit mode I thought it was a vert that some how got there after going to edit mode though it was not there when selecting the face the dot seems to also become selected but still not visible in edit mode when clicking on the dot in object mode it also selects the face so they must be connected somehow I have a mirror mod and a sub surf on the mesh   [image: mystery dot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *just* have a *Mirror* and *Subsurf* modifier on your mesh, you also have a *Particle System*. The dot you are seeing is one of the emitted particles.

To remove the particle system (as it sounds like you didn't intend to have one) first click the highlighted button below to go to the particle system settings:

[image]

Then click the minus button to remove the particle system from your object:

[image]

Comment: If my answer has helped you can mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the tick to the left of it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work